# Confront two counts in where clause through subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

is it legit writing a query structured as this:

```
select *
from x
where Q1 >= Q2
```

Q1 and Q2 are both queries which select a count value. In Q1 I extract the count for the single person (for example) and in Q2 I extract a table with a count divided for each person (through a group by).

Comment: This link might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable

Comment: What do you mean by "legit"? Do you mean "will it work"? In which case, have you tried it? Do you mean "is there a more readable way?" or "is there a faster way?" Also, what does this have to do with jQuery? What does your data look like? Right now, this question is pretty meaningless.

Comment: @Aureate That question references a term I've never heard of, and links to a Wikipedia page as reference which is now deleted. I'm really struggling to understand how such specific answers were given to such a broad question, so if you know what it means, it would be great if you could edit a better definition into the question for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it legit writing a query structured as this:

```
select *
from x
where Q1 >= Q2
```

Yes, as long as both your queries are scalar queries (probably correlated)

```
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE (subquery1) >= (subquery2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is legit.  The code would look like:

```
select x.*
from x
where (select count(. . .) from . . .) >= (select count( . . . ) from . . . );
```

The parentheses around the subqueries are necessary.  A `group by` would *not* be appropriate in the subqueries, because the subqueries could then return more than one row.  If either returns zero rows, then no rows will be returned, because the value used for the comparison is `NULL`.

That said, this would be an unusual construct.  I would recommend that you ask *another* question with sample data and desired results to see if there are alternative ways to write the query.